# Trying to determine which is the active slide in simple slider

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've made a quite simple full page slider which utilises a list and keeps the second list item within viewport. But now I've tried to find a way to give the "active" slide a class (like "active" for example). Since I know that the second li always is the active one I tried to target the nth-child(2) and somehow give it an active class but unfortunately I can't quite get it to work (it gets so cluttered with the approach I try).

Is there an easier way that I'm not seeing?

CodePen is [HERE](https://codepen.io/triphys/pen/jaEKMz)

HTML

```
<div id="slider">
  <ul>
    <li>
        <h1>Slide 1</h1>
        <a href="" class="slider__next">Go to slide 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h1>Slide 2</h1>
        <a href="" class="slider__next">Go to slide 3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h1>Slide 3</h1>
        <a href="" class="slider__next">Go to slide 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h1>Slide 4</h1>
        <a href="" class="slider__next">Go to slide 5</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h1>Slide 5</h1>
        <a href="" class="slider__next">Go to slide 1</a>
    </li>
  </ul>  
</div>
```

CSS

```
#slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  ul {
        position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    li {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        display: block;
      background-color: gray;
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: scroll;
        .content__container {
                max-width: 55%;
                margin: 15% auto 0 auto;
                h1 {
                    color: #fff;
                }
            }
            .navArrow__right {
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                position: fixed;
                top: 50%;
            right: 30px;
            -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
            -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
            -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            p {
                    font-size: 18px;
                    line-height: 26px;
                    margin-bottom: 0;
                    margin-right: 30px;
                    max-width: 140px;
                }
            }
    }
  }
}
```

jQuery

```
initSlider();

$('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

$(window).resize(function(){
  initSlider();
});

$('.slider__next').click(function () {
  event.preventDefault();
  moveRight();
});

//Slider init
function initSlider() {
  var slider = $('#slider');
  var sliderUl = slider.find('ul');
  var sliderItems = slider.find('ul li');
  var sliderCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
  var viewportHeight = $(window).outerHeight();
  var viewportWidth = $(window).outerWidth();
  slider.css({
    width: viewportWidth,
    height: viewportHeight,
  });
  sliderUl.css({ 
    width: sliderItems.outerWidth() * sliderCount,
    height: viewportHeight,
    marginLeft: - viewportWidth,
  });
  sliderItems.css({
    width: viewportWidth,
    height: viewportHeight,
  });
}

//Slider next and slider prev controls
function moveRight() {
  var viewportWidth = $(window).outerWidth();
  $('#slider ul').animate({
    left: - viewportWidth
  }, 500, function () {
    $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
    $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sure add a variable to your code

```
var current  = 0;

moveRight() {
  if(current <= sliderCount) { // not sure atm if silderCount or sliderCount - 1
     current++;
  } else {
     current = 0;
  }
  sliderItems.removeClass('active'); // remove all actives
  $(sliderItems[current]).addClass('active'); // set active
}
```

its not the best js after all imho because this all should be one prototype or something but i think it will work

Answer (score 0):

A small update to your `moveRight` function can be used to remove the `active` class from the previously active slide and add the `active` class to the current slide:

```
  function moveRight() {
    var viewportWidth = $(window).outerWidth();
    $('#slider ul').animate({
      left: - viewportWidth
    }, 500, function () {
      $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
      $('#slider ul').css('left', '');

      // update active slide
      $('#slider ul li.active').removeClass('active');
      $('#slider ul li:nth-child(2)').addClass('active');
    });
  }
```

An updated CodePen is [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GOgbEG#anon-login).